# Generate barcode or qrcode using google vision api

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-vision

I am using google vision API to scan the barcodes and qrcodes. Now I want to give one more facility to the users that user can generate text, url, phone, vcard etc barcodes/qrcodes.

So anybody knows how to achieve this? Because there are lots of app on google play store those are doing the same things.

Comment: If you want to generate barcode you can use zxing library. https://github.com/zxing/zxing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Answer

You can't.

### Reason

I don't know if you are using the cloud or the mobile vision api, but both do not support barcode generation. They can only be used to scan barcodes.

### Alternative

You could use something like [ZXING](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) to generate your barcodes.

Answer (score 0):

i'm try this code to generate Qr it works for me using this code

```
    public static Bitmap generateQrCode(String myCodeText) throws WriterException {
    Hashtable<EncodeHintType, ErrorCorrectionLevel> hintMap = new Hashtable<EncodeHintType, ErrorCorrectionLevel>();
    hintMap.put(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.H); // H = 30% damage
    QRCodeWriter qrCodeWriter = new QRCodeWriter();
    int size = 256;
    BitMatrix bitMatrix= qrCodeWriter.encode(myCodeText,BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, size, size, hintMap);
    int width = bitMatrix.getWidth();
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, width, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < width; y++) {
            bmp.setPixel(y, x, bitMatrix.get(x, y) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
        }
    }
    return bmp;
}
```

try it